# Codename One Sort Table with Data from SQL Database

Tags: database, datatable, codenameone

I am working on an app that retrieves data from a database. The structure I use is from the code example given here : https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/db/Database.html .

My table displays fine with the data.

Now I want to sort the table data in the first column, which contains dates as strings.

What would be the best approach to achieve this? I have tried with code from JTable, but with no success ...

Worthwhile admitting that this is my first Codename One app and that my experiences with Java resume to less than a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two directions you can take, the first is just change the SQL and use the `ORDER BY` clause which will retrieve properly sorted data. The second approach should work dynamically with any table:

For a dynamic sortable table you will need a bit more work. I adapted the existing table sample from the JavaDoc to support sorting. Currently I just did this for string columns but you can probably replace the comparator easily to do what you want...

```
Form hi = new Form("Table", new BorderLayout());
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"}, new Object[][] {
    {"Row 1", "Row A", "Row X"},
    {"Row 2", "Row B", "Row Y"},
    {"Row 3", "Row C", "Row Z"},
    {"Row 4", "Row D", "Row K"},
    }) {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return col != 0;
        }
    };
Table table = new Table(model) {
    private int currentSortedColum = -1;
    private boolean asc;
    private Button lastSortedColumnButton;

    private void setArrow(int column, Button b) {
        if(column == currentSortedColum) {
            if(asc) {
                FontImage.setMaterialIcon(b, FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_UPWARD);
            } else {
                FontImage.setMaterialIcon(b, FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_DOWNWARD);                            
            }
        } else {
            FontImage.setMaterialIcon(b, FontImage.MATERIAL_SORT);   
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) { // (1)
        Component cell;
        if(row == -1) { 
            // table header 
            cell = new Button("" + value, "TableHeader");
            setArrow(column, ((Button)cell));
            ((Button)cell).setTextPosition(LEFT);
            ((Button)cell).addActionListener(e -> {
                if(currentSortedColum != column && lastSortedColumnButton != null) {
                    FontImage.setMaterialIcon(lastSortedColumnButton, FontImage.MATERIAL_SORT);   
                }
                lastSortedColumnButton = (Button)cell;
                if(column == currentSortedColum) {
                    asc = !asc;
                } else {
                    currentSortedColum = column;
                    asc = false;
                }
                setArrow(column, lastSortedColumnButton);
                setModel(new SortedTableModel(currentSortedColum, asc, model, new CaseInsensitiveOrder()));
            });
        } else {
            cell = super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
        }
        if(row > -1 && row % 2 == 0) { 
            // pinstripe effect 
            cell.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xeeeeee);
            cell.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
        }
        return cell;
    }
};
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, table);
hi.show();
```

For this to work you will need the sorted model:

```
class SortedTableModel implements TableModel {
    private TableModel model;
    private int[] sorted;

    public SortedTableModel(int column, boolean asc, TableModel model, Comparator cmp) {
        this.model = model;

        sorted = new int[model.getRowCount()];
        Integer[] sortedTemp = new Integer[sorted.length]; 

        for(int iter = 0 ; iter < sorted.length ; iter++) {
            sortedTemp[iter] = iter;
        }

        // sort(int[]) doesn't accept a comparator how stupid is that...
        Arrays.sort(sortedTemp, (Object o1, Object o2) -> {
                int i1 = (Integer)o1;
                int i2 = (Integer)o2;
                if(asc) {
                    return cmp.compare(model.getValueAt(i1, column), model.getValueAt(i2, column)) * -1;
                }
                return cmp.compare(model.getValueAt(i1, column), model.getValueAt(i2, column));
            }
        );
        for(int iter = 0 ; iter < sorted.length ; iter++) {
            sorted[iter] = sortedTemp[iter];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return model.getRowCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return model.getColumnCount();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int i) {
        return model.getColumnName(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return model.isCellEditable(sorted[row], column);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return model.getValueAt(sorted[row], column);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(int row, int column, Object o) {
        model.setValueAt(sorted[row], column, o);
    }

    @Override
    public void addDataChangeListener(DataChangedListener d) {
        model.addDataChangeListener(d);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeDataChangeListener(DataChangedListener d) {
        model.removeDataChangeListener(d);
    }
}
```

It produces this:

[image: Dynamic table sorting]

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing all the valuable information, I have come with the following solution, which I Found a little more straightforward:

1. Get date from DatePicker as Long value and add to database :

   ```
   Long long_Date = gui_date_Picker.getDate().getTime();
   ```
2. Retrieve string numbers from database, converte into long, convert into date and put into table:

   ```
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Date", "Termin"}, new Object[][] {{}} );
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

   Database db = null;
   Cursor cur = null;

   db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("MyDB2.db");
   db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Termine (Date NOT NULL,Event NOT NULL)");
   cur = db.executeQuery("select * from Termine ORDER BY Date ASC; ");

   while (cur.next()) {

       Row currentRow = cur.getRow();
       String date = currentRow.getString(0);
       String termin = currentRow.getString(1);

       Long l = Long.parseLong(date, 10);
       Date date_from_String = new Date(l);

       String string_from_Date = formatter.format(date_from_String);
       System.out.println(string_from_Date);


       model.addRow(new Object[]{string_from_Date, termin });
   }


   Table table = new Table(model);
   ```